# Google Chrome mobile emulator hiding options in dropdown

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, mobile-emulator

I am working with drop down list on mobiles. For testing purposes I'm using Chrome's mobile emulator. One strange thing I noticed is that in mobile emulation if I have more than two elements in the drop down list they are hidden in a strange way.

HTML I'm using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Dropdown</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of desktop

[image]

Screenshot of mobile

[image]

I'm using chrome version 48.0.2564.97 m. I tried it on my friend's PC who was running Version 47.x.xxxx.xx (don't remember the exact version) and its working fine on that.

Is this a bug in chrome ? Did any of you faced the same issue ? If yes is there any fix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this is a bug in M48. Some refactoring happened and it had some adverse affects. It has been fixed in M49 coming soon™. Trying to see if it is reproducible by any team members in stable and get them to backport to M48 if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I've been wrestling with the same bug for a couple hours,
It does not seem to be related to anything css driven and I confirmed that the bug does not present on chrome on my mobile.

I'm sure it's just a bug in the emulator,
firefox's emulator renders dropdowns fine,

I know this isn't all that helpful I just wanted to confirm that you're not the only one seeing this

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: only just signed up to stack overflow if I had a higher reputation I would have done as you said